# Wordpress- Function defined in functions.php is not found

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following setup in a wordpress theme:

in functions.php i have defined a function called function listing_pins()

in functions.php i also have

```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');

    function load_scripts() {   
    wp_enqueue_script('googlecode_regular', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/google_js/google_map_code.php',array('jquery'), '1.0', true); 
    }
```

and finally the  google_map_code.php file

```
  header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
  include_once("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/wp-load.php"); 
  $general_latitude =  get_option('wp_estate_general_latitude','');
  $general_longitude=  get_option('wp_estate_general_longitude','');
  $place_markers=listing_pins();
  ....
```

I'm not gonna list the whole functions since i don't think they are not relevant for my question.

The setup above works perfectly on my server but on a client setup i receive

**Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function listing_pins() in **/home/content/64/45654654/html/blue/wp-content/themes/wpestax/js/google_js/google_map_code_home.php** on line **6**

Is anything i;m doing wrong ? Wordpress is not aware of the things defined in functions.php when  use wp_enqueue_script ? But in this case why this works on my server and not on client one.

Comment: Why is `google_map_code.php` enqueued as JS file? I'm confused

Comment: Sorry, but you're approaching this in the wrong way. You should never include wp-load.php, [see this article](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/) for reasons why. To achieve what you want you need [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script),[this article](http://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/) together with the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) is a good place to start.

Comment: In php i generate a list of google map locations and output it as js.

Comment: @Mark - ok i understand what is wrong with my approach - but this way could generate the "undefined function" ?

Comment: Strictly speaking I don't think so, but to be frank this method is poor and will almost certainly will lead to more problems. For that reason I can only comment on a better approach. Try it and post back if you can't get it to work.

Comment: Yep- it's clear for me that wp-load.php should not be included and  wp_localize_script should be used instead. My bug was generated by the fact the wp-load was not included.

Comment: I was wondering if is any alternatives for styles . In case i want to generate a css on the fly and don;t want to include wp-load.

Comment: the problem  is likely not related to the piece of code you are showing